# MDD particles instances

Tags: particles

I have been shifting from Lightwave to Blender I made some particles and dynamics which is not adaptable to blender. so few works I've done in Lightwave 3D and export it as MDD with help of plugin. (https://dpont.pagesperso-orange.fr/plugins/MDD_Pointer.html) Now I got the MDD particle showing in blender. But I'm trying to convert it as instances.. texture smoke..etc But I just hold on how to proceed further. As usual in Blender creating known things is a big challenge and nightmare every time for a longtime Blender Beginner. Can anyone help to fix it.
Attached the MDD imported Blender scene.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=osxoP3rE" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/osxoP3rE/)

Comment: Welcome, please place given code into your question ... bellow your description is "Edit" link to adjust your Q. Thanks keep this site organised. :)

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm looking at your file ... usually for MMD import a "Mesh Cache" modifier is used ... but in your file is just a static point cloud without any dynamics. Does it what you want? Did you apply the modifier? In the current file with static point cloud - do you need instance a plane with texture or some volumetric procedural shader? Would be great to share some reference or sketch of desired result. How did you try to instance it?